# Catch C++ signal in Android NDK and still print crash dump

Tags: android, c++, crash, android-ndk

I'm catching C++ signals so I print some debugging information. But doing so I am unable to get the crash dump that the NDK prints when you crash.

Can you manually print the crash dump. I see debuggerd.c (http://kobablog.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/debuggerd-of-android/) does the work but not sure how I would use it. Otherwise is there some way to rethrow the signal without my signal handler catching it and get the crash dump still.

Here is what I currently do:

```
struct sigaction psa, oldPsa;

void CESignalHandler::init() {
    CELogI("Crash handler started");

    psa.sa_sigaction = handleCrash;
    psa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    //sigaction(SIGBUS, &psa, &oldPsa);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &psa, &oldPsa);
    //sigaction(SIGSYS, &psa, &oldPsa);
    //sigaction(SIGFPE, &psa, &oldPsa);
    //sigaction(SIGILL, &psa, &oldPsa);
    //sigaction(SIGHUP, &psa, &oldPsa);
}

void CESignalHandler::handleCrash(int signalNumber, siginfo_t *sigInfo, void *context) {
    static volatile sig_atomic_t fatal_error_in_progress = 0;
    if (fatal_error_in_progress) //Stop a signal loop.
        _exit(1);
    fatal_error_in_progress = 1;

    char* j;
    asprintf(&j, "Crash Signal: %d, crashed on: %x, UID: %ld\n", signalNumber, (long) sigInfo->si_addr, (long) sigInfo->si_uid);  //%x prints out the faulty memory address in hex
    CELogE(j);

    CESignalHandler::getStackTrace();
    sigaction(signalNumber, &oldPsa, NULL); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset the signal handler(s) to the previous function, and then crash again -- ideally at the point where the signal was originally thrown.  You can do this by passing a `struct sigaction` in as the 3rd argument to `sigaction()`, and using the saved value to restore the original behavior in the signal handler.

This can be a bit tricky because of the way debuggerd works (and because the way it works has changed over time).  For a "hard" failure like a segmentation fault, returning from the signal handler just causes the same signal to be re-thrown.  The Android crash handler uses this to its advantage by contacting debuggerd, waiting for it to attach with ptrace, and then resuming.  debuggerd then gets to watch the process as it crashes (for the second time).

This doesn't work for "soft" failures, e.g. somebody manually sends your process a `SIGABRT` or gets a `SIGPIPE` from a `write()`.  If the signal handler contacts debuggerd and resumes, the process just clears the signal and continues on, leaving debuggerd to wait indefinitely for a second crash that never happens.  This was partially fixed a couple of releases back; now the debug code re-issues the signal itself (which doesn't actually do anything until the signal handler returns, because the signal is blocked while the handler runs).  This usually works, and when it doesn't, debuggerd will time out and drop the connection.

So.  If you receive a segmentation fault or bus error, you can just restore the original signal handler and then return from yours, and when the process crashes again the debuggerd handler will deal with it.  If somebody sent you a `SIGHUP`, you should handle it entirely yourself, because debuggerd doesn't care about that signal at all.

Things get weird with `SIGFPE`.  This is a "soft" failure, because most ARM CPUs don't have a hardware integer divide instruction, and the signal is actually being sent explicitly from the libgcc `__div0` function.  You can restore the signal handler, and then re-send the signal yourself; but depending on what version of Android you're running you might have to send it twice.  Ideally you'd like to be doing this from the code that encountered the arithmetic problem, rather than the signal handler, but that's tricky unless you can replace `__div0`.  You would need to send the signal with `tgkill()`, not `kill()`, as the latter will result in the signal being sent to the main thread of the process, which would cause debuggerd to dump the stack for the wrong thread.

You might be tempted to copy the handler out of `bionic/linker/debugger.cpp`, but that's a bad idea -- the protocol used to communicate between bionic and debuggerd has changed in the past and will likely change again.

Comment: Lets just worry about segmentation faults for now. 
I still can't get it to work. I restore the old handler like so:
sigaction(signalNumber, &oldPsa, NULL); but I'm still not getting a android crash dump. I've updated the first post to show this.
It shows "06-25 10:43:40.143: D/Zygote(159): Process 4588 terminated by signal (11)" in the logcat.

Great post btw.

Comment: To be fully correct, you should have a separate oldPsa for each signal.  I think it will work if you just remove `sigaction(SIGHUP, &psa, &oldPsa)` from your existing code -- that's executing last, which means oldPsa holds the original `SIGHUP` handler.  Bionic doesn't install a debuggerd handler for `SIGHUP`, so you're getting `SIG_DFL`.

Comment: Ok for now I'll comment out all of them but the SIGSEGV. I believe I'm nearly there, it crashed a little nicely this time but still no dump.
I got his in the logcat: "06-25 11:30:13.464: I/DEBUG(31996): timed out waiting for tid=9202 to die 
06-25 11:30:13.464: I/DEBUG(31996): ptrace detach from 9202 failed: No such process 
06-25 11:30:13.464: I/DEBUG(31996): debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie! 
06-25 11:30:13.484: I/DEBUG(9796): debuggerd: Feb  8 2013 22:00:43"

Comment: Wait I got it. I removed the call to Android which causes my app to full crash and it printed the dump!

Comment: I still got to fully crash the app, but you have solved my main issue.  I had searched high and low for a solution on the net, I had thought all was lost :P Thank you for your help!

Comment: Problem now that I'm stuck on is that it will go into a crash loop.
I can't throw a Java exception from the signal code otherwise I wont get the crash dump. I tried to set a flag to crash the app when it does use the native code, but my flag is set to null because of the native crash. Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: I can't quite picture what you're trying to do.  You may want to file a new question so you can write more than 600 chars.  Were you hoping to recover from a `SIGSEGV`?  Doing "heavy" things, like calling back into the VM, is unwise from a signal handler -- you can't know what state the app was in when it failed.  If all you need is the current thread's stack dump, you might want to see if you can extract libcorkscrew and use it directly (the Dalvik VM uses it to get native traces when it receives a `SIGQUIT`).

Comment: I might create a new question about it tomorrow if I am still stuck. Basically I want to crash the app. Currently it's getting in a crash loop since android continues to reopen the activity. To the user it looks like the app has just frozen black screen (which back does nothing). Thanks again.

Comment: Why is Android restarting it?  Is this a service or a replacement for part of the system?  Is something actively re-launching it?  Usually when an app process dies the system doesn't restart it.  What does `logcat -v threadtime` show?  (I want to be sure the process is dying and being restarted, vs. a thread being restarted -- sometimes "fatal" signals don't kill the process when handlers get in the way.)

Comment: "Why is Android restarting it" 
Doesn't look like I'm the only one when you catch signals.
"Is this a service" 
Not a service.
"I want to be sure the process is dying and being restarted" 
It is. All my static vars are wiped.
"sometimes "fatal" signals don't kill" 
I guess that is the case. 
I've taken too much time on this so I might just use the google breakpad lib and hopefully that has what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You need call `oldPsa` manually like this

```
oldPsa(signalNumber, sigInfo, context)
```